# Can .asp & .aspx pages work if placed in same virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, virtual-directory

Can .asp & .aspx pages work if placed in same virtual directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is YES and I have used such configuration in past.

Long answer is there are unlikely chances of having trouble - essentially, both ASP and ASP.NET will run within same application pool and hence same worker process and there can be issues related to the same. For example, ASP page is using COM components written .NET version higher (or different) than ASP.NET version that you are using and ASP.NET code gets triggered earlier loading CLR with lower version within process - which may cause an issue for .NET code for COM components.

The best way is to try it and test it to reasonable extent.